# I cannot install applications because Ubuntu cannot set the locale?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, permissions, postgresql

I am logged on as root.

Whenever I want to install a new application whether locally or remotely I get this :

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up postgresql-9.3 (9.3.14-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                              * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2016-09-06 15:47:37 CEST FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433.lock": Permission denied
                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed."
```

Why does Ubuntu start the Postgre Server ?
What's the deal here ?
Please give simple answers ... rookie here.

output of `locale`

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en 
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: what's the output of `locale`?

Comment: locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: sorry I should have said [edit] your question to add info :) I did it for you anyway. Your `LC_CTYPE` looks screwy. Did you do anything that might have caused this? You might try running `sudo locale-gen en_US.utf8` to see if that magically fixes it

Comment: Kudos :) ...... But that didn't work ... The thing is that this machine has a Postgre server 9.2.4 running. I think the company which set it up might have locked access to any other postgre instances to avoid conflicts or something like that. D'you know why ubuntu needs to run a postgre server to install applications ?

Comment: Safe to say I don't know what's going on there, +1 for your efforts and I hope someone else can help!

Comment: Bumpety bump ... ? Anyone /

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have 3 distinct problems here.

1. A half-installed postgresql-9.3 seems to be on the system, so when you try to `apt-get install` any new package, it tries to finish the postgresql install first. This is the normal APT behavior.
2. The permissions of /var/run/postgresql are incorrect, hence the error
   `could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433.lock": Permission denied`, which whould happen even if the rest was OK.
3. Your `locale` settings `en_US.UTF-8` are borked, as if someone deleted underlying files, hence the advice from @Zanna to regenerate them with `sudo locale-gen en_US.utf8`

If you're primarily interested in fixing #1, I think you want to uninstall the half-installed postgresql-9.3

In your case, I would start by a command like this:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev}\t${binary:Package}\n' 'postgres*'
```

To obtain the list of postgres packages and their status. Then uninstall and purge the ones that are in error or half-installed.